# Want to add value in MySql from form table

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have tried to figure out this for a period now but have not yet found a solution. I'm still in learning stage and this is my first project to make a website form scratch.

I have a form where there is a table that the user can fill in information and add new rows.

**I wonder how I can save this in MySql.**

*Hope you can help me with this.*

Html code looks like this

```
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="tab_logic">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Varenavn</th>
            <th>Mengde</th>
            <th>Enhet</th>
            <th>Pris</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><a id="add_row" class="btn btn-success pull-right">Add Row</a><a id='delete_row' class="pull-right btn btn-danger">Delete Row</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
       <tr id='addr0'>
            <td>1</td>
            <td><input type="text" name='v_navn0' placeholder='Varenavn' class="form-control" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name='mengde0' placeholder='Mengde' class="form-control" /></td>
            <td><select name='enhet0' placeholder='Enhet' class='form-control input-md'><option>KG</option><option>GR</option><option>L</option<option>DL</option></select></td>
            <td><input type="text" name='pris0' placeholder='Pris' class="form-control" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id='addr1'></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And her is my JavaScript code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var i = 1;
    $("#add_row").click(function () {
        $('#addr' + i).html("<td>" + (i + 1) + "</td><td><input name='v_name" + i + "' type='text' placeholder='Varenavn' class='form-control input-md'  /> </td><td><input  name='mengde" + i + "' type='text' placeholder='Mengde'  class='form-control input-md'></td><td><select name='enhet" + i + "' placeholder='Enhet'  class='form-control input-md'><option>KG</option><option>GR</option><option>L</option><option>DL</option></select></td</td></td><td><input name='pris" + i + "' type='text' placeholder='Pris' class='form-control input-md'  />");

        $('#tab_logic').append('<tr id="addr' + (i + 1) + '"></tr>');
        i++;
    });
    $("#delete_row").click(function () {
        if (i > 1) {
            $("#addr" + (i - 1)).html('');
            i--;
        }
    });

 });
```

And here is my Query

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

// definding names
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
$navn = ($_POST["navn"]);
$antall = ($_POST["antall"]);
$holdbar = ($_POST["holdbar"]);
$fremgang = ($_POST["fremgang"]);
$allergen = ($_POST["allergen"]);
$varenavn = ($_POST["v_navn0"]);
$mengde = ($_POST["mengde0"]);
$enhet = ($_POST["enhet0"]);
$pris = ($_POST["pris0"])     
}

// Query

$sql = "INSERT INTO oppskrift (opp_navn, antall, holdbarhet, beskrivelse, allergen, varenavn, mengde, enhet, pris)
VALUES ('$navn', '$antall', '$holdbar', '$fremgang', '$allergen', '$varenavn', '$mengde', '$enhet', '$pris')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {

// Redirect to login page
                header("location: /bin/appdata/ny_opp.php");

            } else{
                echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }

$conn->close();
?>
```

and this is my table

```
CREATE TABLE `oppskrift` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `opp_navn` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `antall` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `holdbarhet` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `beskrivelse` TEXT NULL,
    `allergen` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `varenavn` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `mengde` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `enhet` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `pris` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=16
;
```

Comment: It looks like you already have an `INSERT` statement to save data to the database.  What exactly isn't working?

Comment: It wil only show the first row input from user. Not when they add new row. the value they insert then wil not be uploded to the server.

Comment: You refer only to the first row by `$varenavn = ($_POST["v_navn0"]);`. You should put it in some kind of cycle and go through it as `$_POST["v_navn0"]`, `$_POST["v_navn1"]` until you reach null values. Also you should call insert for every of the iteration

Comment: But im not sure how many rows they will put in. If i have to go from 0-1000 the code would be long and the codefile large.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be that your PHP only checks for the first row's variable names. What I would do is to replace this names with arrays, so I could iterate over it and get all the rows. What follows it probably not the best way, but it works:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="tab_logic">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Varenavn</th>
            <th>Mengde</th>
            <th>Enhet</th>
            <th>Pris</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><a id="add_row" class="btn btn-success pull-right">Add Row</a><a id='delete_row' class="pull-right btn btn-danger">Delete Row</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
       <tr id='addr0'>
            <td>1</td>
            <td><input type="text" name='v_navn0' placeholder='Varenavn' class="form-control" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name='mengde[]' placeholder='Mengde' class="form-control" /></td>
            <td><select name='enhet[]' placeholder='Enhet' class='form-control input-md'><option>KG</option><option>GR</option><option>L</option<option>DL</option></select></td>
            <td><input type="text" name='pris[]' placeholder='Pris' class="form-control" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id='addr1'></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var i = 1;
    $("#add_row").click(function () {
        $('#addr' + i).html("<td>" + (i + 1) + "</td><td><input name='v_navn[]' type='text' placeholder='Varenavn' class='form-control input-md'  /> </td><td><input  name='mengde[]' type='text' placeholder='Mengde'  class='form-control input-md'></td><td><select name='enhet[]' placeholder='Enhet'  class='form-control input-md'><option>KG</option><option>GR</option><option>L</option><option>DL</option></select></td</td></td><td><input name='pris[]' type='text' placeholder='Pris' class='form-control input-md'  />");

        $('#tab_logic').append('<tr id="addr' + (i + 1) + '"></tr>');
        i++;
    });
    $("#delete_row").click(function () {
        if (i > 1) {
            $("#addr" + (i - 1)).html('');
            i--;
        }
    });

 });
```

And the PHP:

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

// definding names
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
$navn = ($_POST["navn"]);
$antall = ($_POST["antall"]);
$holdbar = ($_POST["holdbar"]);
$fremgang = ($_POST["fremgang"]);
$allergen = ($_POST["allergen"]);
$varenavn = ($_POST["v_navn"]);
$mengde = ($_POST["mengde"]);
$enhet = ($_POST["enhet"]);
$pris = ($_POST["pris"])     
}

// Query
foreach($varenavn as $i => $var) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO oppskrift (opp_navn, antall, holdbarhet, beskrivelse, allergen, varenavn, mengde, enhet, pris)
VALUES ('$navn', '$antall', '$holdbar', '$fremgang', '$allergen', '$varenavn[$i]', '$mengde[$i]', '$enhet[$i]', '$pris[$i]')";
    if ($conn->query($sql) !== TRUE) {
         echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
    }
}
// Redirect to login page
header("location: /bin/appdata/ny_opp.php");

$conn->close();
?>
```

Something like this. I haven't tested it, but you get the idea.

Comment: Thx, i will try it out and let you know how it went!

Comment: delCano, It worked, but not. It insert correct, but agen only the first insert value and now its onlye showing the first letterand not the hole word.

Comment: OK, add a `print_r($_POST); exit;` in your PHP and tell me the result.

Comment: Array
(
[navn] =&gt; asdsadsa
[antall] =&gt; dasdsadsada
[holdbar] =&gt; sds
[fremgang] =&gt; das
[allergen] =&gt; sds
[v_name] =&gt; Array
([0] =&gt; sasdsad [1] =&gt; sadsadas[2] =&gt; adsad)
[mengde] =&gt; Array
([0] =&gt; sadsd[1] =&gt; dsadsad [2] =&gt; sadasd)[enhet] =&gt; Array
        (
            [0] =&gt; KG
            [1] =&gt; KG
            [2] =&gt; KG
        )

    [pris] =&gt; Array
        (
            [0] =&gt; asdad
            [1] =&gt; sadsad
            [2] =&gt; sadasdas
        )

)

Comment: For the exampel i just added som values. In my server it now only shows up as the last input (array [2]) not all of them

Comment: OK, so as you can see v_name, mengde, emhet and pris are all 3-element arrays, so you know the server has received all three lines you added. Therefore, you should have been able to iterate over them via foreach or, if you prefer, a for loop. 

I just realized that, in my code, I should have added an 'exit();' after the echo error line, so it does stop there and show the message; but I still can not see any reason why it isn't working for you. Can you post a link to a pastebin with your PHP so I have a look?

Comment: I will do it tomorrow after my work. I live in norway so now its amost 24.00. 
Only the php action page ? If its the page whit the form on its on my webpage. Din-matmerking.no under oppskrift and under ny oppskrift.

Comment: And I am resiving some info on the server. But some times it show only one letter and other times it shows only the last input.

Comment: The link is already invalid, I didn't have time to look at it.

Comment: I will post new today

Comment: Ok, you're not using `foreach` right.  What foreach does is loop on the array, and execute for each iteration the following block `{ ... }`. Look at my code for an example. What you are doing is iterating on each array without doing anything, and then do the query. Not at all what you want.

Comment: Its working in a way. Only problem is that it now ads a new row in on the server data table for every new row i put in the form. So if i put 10 new rows in the form, i get 10 diffrent rows on the server

Comment: Well yes. Wasn't that what you wanted?

Comment: No. What I'm trying to do is to have all values they put in to go in one row, so i can display it later. 
The form is a place for the user to make a food recepie. And "Varenavn" is norwegian for the name of the food. Like Egg. "Menge" is amount and "enhet" is KG/Punds. 
So they make a recepie with a name (navn), they input wich ingrediens they use, the amount and the cost (pris) for the ithem. And then they can display it and print it out. 
So if they the value goes in different arrays it will display each array in different recepies.

Comment: Oh, OK. Then, that is a completely new problem. Your DB architecture is wrong then. You can't define an undefinite amount of columns on a table. What you should have is two tables, a "Recipe" and an "Ingredient"; and then define a "one-to-many" relationship. I could help you with this, but I don't hink this comment section is the best place for this.

Comment: Okey. Yes, i would like to have some help. Where would be bether to do this? Facebook or skype or some other place?

Comment: Find me on skype: elkano_